# Preserve autoscale when clearing axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I want to make a series of plots (meant for creating an animation) and thus I want to reuse the axes and preserve the x and y limits across all plots, so I set `ax.autoscale(False)`. However, when I clear the axes using plt.cla() to draw the next image, the autoscale setting is overridden so I have to set `ax.autoscale(False)` and the x and y limits *on every iteration*.

```
In [49]: fig = plt.figure(1)

In [50]: ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

In [59]: ax.get_autoscale_on()
Out[59]: True

In [60]: ax.autoscale(False)

In [61]: ax.get_autoscale_on()
Out[61]: False

In [62]: plt.cla()

In [63]: ax.get_autoscale_on()
Out[63]: True
```

so I end up doing `ax.lines = []` or `ax.lines.pop()`, but this forces me to set the color on each plot to avoid the color cycling. If I set `hold` to `False`, then the autoscale setting is reset every time I call `ax.plot()`. Is there any other way to preserve the axes properties while removing all plots?

Comment: Why not just update the artist's data instead of making a call to `plot` each time?

Comment: No idea how can I do that. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Don't call `plt.cla()`, it will **clear** current axes. If you want to create animation, use `matplotlib.pyplot.draw()` instead which will **redraw** the current figure and I think it's what you want.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ion()
ax=plt.subplot(111)

line1, = ax.plot(x,y,label='x')

for i in xrange(20):
 #update your data to new x,y
 line1.set_xdata(x)
 line1.set_ydata(y)
 draw()
```

The [CookBook of Matplotlib](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) has some good examples on animations, you may want to check it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the Cookbook link! I am going to check your code and some of the performance improvements that are suggested.

Comment: Well, the key is the `line.set_data` trick, which does the magic I needed, but your example and the ones that appear in the Cookbook seem useless to me as they update the animation with the speed of a `for` loop - the page itself states that the info is very outdated, and the new animation API (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html) seems more valuable. In fact, if I add a `sleep()` call in the loop, misteriously it doesn't update at all until I ^C.

Comment: What if points on the plot are moving? This methods only works if data is added at each step but not if points are removed or need to be redrawn at other coordinates.